# How to ignore rows that violate foreign key constraint in Postgres INSERT INTO?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

In this sql statement

```
INSERT INTO child (parentId, value) SELECT parentId, value FROM temptable
```

`child.parentId` is a foreign key pointing to `parent.id`. Rows in the `parent` table might be deleted at any time while this long-running `INSERT INTO` statement (that could insert up to a few million rows) is running.

If the `child` table has no corresponding foreign key in `parent` **before** the `INSERT INTO` statement begins running, or if a row in the `parent` table referenced from `child` was deleted **while** this `INSERT INTO` is running, I'd like the `INSERT INTO` to silently ignore that particular row (and simply skip inserting into `child` the rows that violate the foreign key constraint) rather than the whole statement failing.

How can I accomplish this? I'm not familiar with how any race conditions would work in this case.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to lock referenced rows of the table `parent` in `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO child (parent_id, value) 
    SELECT t.parent_id, t.value
    FROM temptable t
    JOIN parent p ON t.parent_id = p.id
    FOR UPDATE OF p;
```

Note however that this preventive locking may significantly increase the execution time in case when the table `parent` is intensively modified by other transactions at the same time.

As a remedy you can consider to perform the insertion in several transactions by dividing the data into logical partitions, e.g.

```
INSERT 
    ...
    WHERE parent_id < 1000

INSERT 
    ...
    WHERE parent_id BETWEEN 1001 AND 2000 -- and so on.
```